# Trying to write generic code for a board game

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I'm actually working on a board game using unity. It's a board game where players have to connect two opposites borders by claiming empty hexagonal cases. Borders are assigned to players at the beginning.

I chose to represent my empty cases with gems, white when unclaimed, and red or blue for players. So I made a single prefab for all gems.

To check connections between gems themselves and with borders, I assigned to them slightly bigger box colliders so they are colliding (trigger) with other objects, so I can detect if a claimed gem is connected (directly or not) to a border. I wrote this code generically as gems are one single prefab, naively thinking that every entity would run its own version of the script.. But that's not the case.

So I'm looking for an alternative way to detect connections with borders, but still generically, as the size of the board is variable.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I would encourage you to shorten this question to something specific. There is a lot of extra information that is not relevant, and you risk getting closed.

Comment: Your question looks very promising and interesting, but I agree with @RufusL, please improve your question.

Comment: What you need to do is create an algorithm that will look at the board every time a move has been made. I shouldn't be using collision detection. I wish I could help you make one but I don't know how. I just know that's what you need. 

You need something along the lines of a 19 by 19 array or list. Then every turn have your game make all the changes it needs to make using that list. 


Ex. A1 is red, A2 is blue, and B2 is blue. Then fill in what your game needs to do in that case.

Comment: That was my second thought. But I can't imagine how I will handle all those prefabs generically (almost 200 gems in the biggest board). I can't easily use positions as my board isn't a square or a rectangle. But I may have an idea that can only work if there is a way to count prefabs or mark them to indicate their position in the board without rewriting code or create specific objects for all 200 of them..

Comment: for representing hexagonal boards, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1838656/1715004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is closely related on how you break your game in game objects and components on Unity3D.

First of all, use scripts to define components. For example your gems could have a script that contains data related to its state (your white, red and blue gems meaning empty, playerA and playerB).

You will probably need a game object (normally called a `GameManager`) to handle all behavior related to game rules like which player is playing, if a player can pick a specific gem and if a player won the game. Depending on the game complexity is a good idea to also have a game object with a component (script) to keep your board state, instead of simply getting it from the gems objects Transform component.

After you have structured your game you do not need colliders to detect connections. Every time you have to check for connections, just iterate over your gems or use your board state object.

**Edit:**

References to help you develop your game:

- [How do I represent a hextile/hex grid in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1838656/1715004)
- [Creating a holder for game level for simple board tile based game.](http://android-by-example.blogspot.com.br/2013/08/scriptable-objects-in-unity3d-creating.html)
- [creating 2d table\chess board\2d array](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/703786/creating-2d-tablechess-board2d-array.html)

Comment: Using the links you gave me, I was able to create something working. I list my gems in a two dimensional array, and when a player claims one, a function is called to look over the array with for loops, and if a gem is claimed by the player who clicked, it calls a little algorithm that looks all directly connected gems. If one is of the same color and connected to a border, the center gem's border connection boolean goes true. It does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for this !

Comment: You are welcome! You can try improving your question to get a better score and ranking. The heart of your question is very common (directions on how develop a game using unity), and it can help other people.